# OpenCL: Можно ли передать в kernel двумерный массив (вот так: __global float **array)?

Tags: c, opencl

Мне нужно выполнить вычисления на GPU с квадратной матрицей(N*N) на OpenCL C. Возникает вопрос, можно ли передать в __kernel двумерный массив: __global float **array или мне нужно использовать одномерный массив?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35442603/9630063

Comment: https://community.khronos.org/t/2-dimensions-array/2022